# Como conseguir o valor inteiro de uma das constantes de um enum?

Tags: c#, enums, cast

Tenho um enum (enumeração) chamando `Notas` e preciso obter o inteiro correspondente a uma de suas constantes.

```
public enum Nota
{
    Otimo = 5,
    MuitoBom = 4,
    Bom = 3,
    Regular = 2,
    Ruim = 1,
    Insuficiente = 0
}
```

Tentei o seguinte, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
aluno.Nota = Nota.MuitoBom;
```

A propriedade `Conceito` é do tipo inteiro e mesmo assim não consigo pegar o valor inteiro da constante `Nota.MuitoBom`, pois o compilador diz que não pode converter implicitamente o tipo `Nota` para `int`.

Comment: Pode adicionar a mensagem exata de erro reporta pelo compilador? (E acho que vc se confundiu ao incluir a resposta na perguna. Os códigos estão iguais)

Answer (score 8):

Se você está manipulando o enum de forma *tipada*, como o tipo `Nota`, basta um cast simples:

```
public static void ImprimirNotaComoInteiro(Nota nota)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)nota);
}
```

Agora, se estiver manipulando como [System.Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx), utilize o método [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (já que a conversão via cast simples não é possível):

```
public static void ImprimirEnumComoInteiro(Enum valorEnum)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(valorEnum));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode obter o resultado esperado realizando uma [conversão explicita (cast)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173105.aspx) já que os dados são de tipos diferentes (`Nota` e `int`). Basta você utilizar o operador de conversão/cast com o tipo de dado que você deseja, no caso seria `int`.

```
aluno.Nota = (int)Nota.MuitoBom;
```